# How to receive dbus signals when there is a webserver running forever?

Tags: python, webserver, dbus

Hey guys I was planning to make my webserver works with dbus signal receiving. The webserver runs with gevent.WSGIServer because I need the support of websocket, while the dbus is handled via python-dbus package.

The question is:

1. webserver always has an event loop running forever, however to
   receive dbus signals, python-dbus requires another event loop (which
   is mainloop) to run forever as well.
2. I am not able to make the webserver running while keeping snooping
   to dbus signals.

Here are my codes:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = logging.getLogger('Rocket.Errors')
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))

    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    app = Bottle()

    # Register the dbus recieve handler
    #bus.add_signal_receiver(hostHeartBeatSignal)
    bus.add_signal_receiver(testSignal)

    **This will block the webserver from running!!!!!!!!**
    mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
    mainloop.run()

    @app.route('/websocket', skip = True)
    def handle_websocket():
        print "Entering websocket handling"
        wsock = request.environ.get('wsgi.websocket')
        if not wsock:
            abort(400, 'Expected WebSocket request.')
        while True:
            try:
                message = wsock.receive()
                print "Message received"
                wsock.send("Your message was: %r" % message)
                print "Message sent"
            except WebSocketError:
                break


    default_cert = os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'share',
                    os.path.basename(__file__), 'cert.pem')

    from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
    from geventwebsocket import WebSocketError
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 443), app, keyfile = default_cert,
                        certfile = default_cert,
                         handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run one of those main loops in another thread.

Comment: Though you do not have reuptation to comments on question, it is not a good way to represent. Better wait until you have proper reputation to comment